# Cufon Styling for main navigation

Tags: html, css, cufon

In this website:
http://theoew.uuuq.com/portfolios/Idea/
I use Cufon to style the text for the the main navigation. I have use this html code for it.

```
<ul id="mainnav" class="alignright">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
            <span>Home</span>
            <small class="active">main page</small>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>About</span>
            <small class="active">my bio</small>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have one problem with it however.
When I hover over the #mainnav li span and then immediately move the mouse down so its hovering over the #mainnav li small text beneath it the #mainnav li span thinks the mouse is still on top of it and stays in its hover state. This does not happen when I don't hover over the #mainnav li small after hovering over the #mainnav li span.

I'm using this code with Cufon:

```
Cufon.replace('#mainnav li a span', {
    hover: true,
    hoverables: { span: true, small: true }
});
```

Its really essential that I get this fixed so I would really appreciate any help.

Note: The site is by no means finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey. I did not runt the code but you could try to add the small tag into you cufon replace .....

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {      
                Cufon.replace('h1, #mainnav li a span, #mainnav li a small', {
                    hover: true,
                    hoverables: { span: true, small: true }

                });
            });
        </script>
```